# Select 2 rows based on datetime value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a database which is running on  SQL Server 2014.

`Activityid = 3` means: log in

`Activityid = 4` means: log out

Rownr is not a column (it indicates the number of the row)

Scenario 1)
The database contains a table with the following rows. I would like to select let say row 6 and 7 if the given datetime is `2015-03-07 08:06:53.625`. Because the given datetime falls between the `StartTime` value of row 6 and 7. How can I achieve this?

Scenario 2)
The `Activityid 4` is missing at row 5. How can I select rows with missing `Activityid` 3 or 4?

```
Rownr   UserName    StartTime               Activityid  Value
1       Anneleen    2015-03-07 07:01:38.707 3           5811
2       Anneleen    2015-03-07 08:52:23.417 4           5811
3       Anneleen    2015-03-07 08:52:34.347 3           5811
4       Anneleen    2015-03-07 14:15:20.140 4           5811
5       Arnold      2015-03-07 11:03:20.420 3           5840
6       Dimitri     2015-03-07 07:02:53.633 3           5817
7       Dimitri     2015-03-07 21:24:20.633 4           5817
```

**Rownr is not a column of the table. I've just added it to the result so I can point out which rows I want as result.**

Comment: for scenario 1, row 1 and 2 work as well. right?

Comment: Hi Julien, you've got a point there. It seems that different users can log in at the same time. So if the given time is 2015-03-07 08:06:53.625, the result will also show row 1 and 2. 

I think the query needs one more parameter which is the column 'Value'.

Comment: what do you mean with value? biggest value wins and only show 1 row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns rows 1-2 and 6-7 because `ActivityId` 3 is before `2015-03-07 08:06:53.625` and `ActivityId` 4 is after `2015-03-07 08:06:53.625` for the 2 of them.

***Note***: Since there is no unique ID column, I supposed that there is no duplicates in [StartTime] for a [UserName].

#### Query 1 ([link](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/448170#resultSets)):

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2015-03-07 08:06:53.625';

WITH list AS (
    SELECT *
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [StartTime])
    FROM data
    WHERE [Activityid] IN (3, 4)
)
SELECT * 
FROM list l1
INNER JOIN list l2 ON l1.UserName = l2.UserName AND l1.n+1 = l2.n 
WHERE l1.Activityid = 3 AND l2.Activityid = 4
    AND l1.StartTime < @date AND l2.StartTime > @date;
```

Output 1:

```
Rownr   | UserName  | StartTime                     | Activityid    | Value | n | Rownr | UserName  | StartTime                     | Activityid    | Value | n
1       | Anneleen  | 2015-03-07 07:01:38.7070000   | 3             | 5811  | 1 | 2     | Anneleen  | 2015-03-07 08:52:23.4170000   | 4             | 5811  | 2
6       | Dimitri   | 2015-03-07 07:02:53.6330000   | 3             | 5817  | 1 | 7     | Dimitri   | 2015-03-07 21:24:20.6330000   | 4             | 5817  | 2
```

---

Using the same CTE this query returns rows where `ActivityId` 3 or 4 has no matching `ActivityId` 4 or 3.

#### Query 2 ([link](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/448170#resultSets)):

```
WITH list AS (
    SELECT *
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [StartTime])
    FROM data
    WHERE [Activityid] IN (3, 4)
)
SELECT l1.* , *
FROM list l1
LEFT JOIN list l2
    ON l1.UserName = l2.UserName AND l1.n+1 = l2.n AND l2.Activityid = 4
WHERE l1.Activityid = 3 AND l2.Activityid IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT l1.* , *
FROM list l1
LEFT JOIN list l2 ON l1.UserName = l2.UserName AND l1.n-1 = l2.n AND l2.Activityid = 3
WHERE l1.Activityid = 4 AND l2.Activityid IS NULL;
```

#### Output 2:

```
Rownr   | UserName  | StartTime                     | Activityid    | Value | n
5       | Arnold    | 2015-03-07 11:03:20.4200000   | 3             | 5840  | 1
8       | Dimitri   | 2015-03-07 22:24:20.6330000   | 4             | 5817  | 3
```

#### Data used with an extra row for 4 without 3:

```
declare @data table
    ([Rownr] int, [UserName] varchar(8), [StartTime] datetime2, [Activityid] int, [Value] int)
;

INSERT INTO @data
    ([Rownr], [UserName], [StartTime], [Activityid], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'Anneleen', '2015-03-07 07:01:38.707', 3, 5811),
    (2, 'Anneleen', '2015-03-07 08:52:23.417', 4, 5811),
    (3, 'Anneleen', '2015-03-07 08:52:34.347', 3, 5811),
    (4, 'Anneleen', '2015-03-07 14:15:20.140', 4, 5811),
    (5, 'Arnold', '2015-03-07 11:03:20.420', 3, 5840),
    (6, 'Dimitri', '2015-03-07 07:02:53.633', 3, 5817),
    (7, 'Dimitri', '2015-03-07 21:24:20.633', 4, 5817),
    (8, 'Dimitri', '2015-03-07 22:24:20.633', 4, 5817);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1**
Only works under the assumption that there only 2 activities a day.

```
    SELECT * FROM TEST  WHERE rownr = (
    SELECT MIN(rownr)
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY [Value],YEAR(STARTTIME),MONTH(STARTTIME),DAY(Starttime)
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

**Scenario 2**

Not the best and precise solution and has definitly some limits but this should work. A more performant solution is to use NOT IN in the WHERE clause.

```
    SELECT [Value],Cast(STARTTIME AS DATE) FROM TEST WHERE [ActivityId] = 3
    Except
    SELECT [Value],Cast(STARTTIME AS DATE) FROM TEST WHERE [ActivityId] = 4
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that rownr is not a column of the table. I've just added it to the result so I can point out which rows I want as result.